# WPF Static 'cue' Image in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How in WPF can you set a static icon to appear in a ComboBox, that is there no matter what you type or select?

Here is an example from the Team Explorer view in Visual Studio 2012 of an image that appears inside the text box:

[image]

I would like to achieve this but with a ComboBox.

Comment: you can find a  sample here in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183106/wpf-static-cue-image-in-combobox . Let us know if you face difficulty.The main thing is that you have to have a "item template" for your combobox control where you specify how your item should look .

Comment: @srsyogesh: why would you link this question as a source, mislink?

Comment: oops , i made a mistake :( Thanks @Djerry for pointing it out. The original link is http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182759/WPF-Country-Combobox .

Comment: I guess you are talking about an editable combobox, and you want that image to be in the textbox, not next to the persons in your popup part of the combobox?